# How to 2D-plot function in two varibles

Tags: plotting

I try to make a plot of a function in multi variables as in that paper   [arXiv:1312.1935](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.1935v3.pdf), FIG. 2 .

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried some thing like:

```
k[s_,f_] = s + f;

ListPlot[Table[k[s, f], {s, -1, 1, 0.5}, {f, -1, 1, 0.5}]]
```

But it plotted k[s, f] on the y- axis. While I'd like to have s and f on the x and y axises.

There is also ContourPlot, or PlotRegion, but to my knowledge the function k[s,f] will be plotted as continuous regions, while i'd like to present it as points (with known values like in the FIG).

So any help ?

---

`" If the data is 3D and the third entry is obtained by applying a
  function like k[s,f] to the first two entries (like data set dt3d
  below), then the function we use to style the data is slightly
  different:"`

Actually I don't understand from here. I understand in the example of `td` and `styleddt` that in `Style[{##}` and `k[##]`, that `##` refers to the two variables which `k` is function of them.

But now I try to plot another function, like `Y[s,f,d]= s+f+d;`, with `-1 < s < 1`, `f= 0.5`, and `-0.5 < d < 0.5`, and I want to plot `Y[s,f,d]` only at `-2 < Y < 0`, or  we can use Piecewise as before to know `Y` values.

Comment: Maybe `ListContourPlot[Table[k[s, f], {s, -1, 1, 0.5}, {f, -1, 1, 0.5}], 
 DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]`?

Comment: It gives me similar for `ContourPlot`, divided regions not list of points.

Comment: `k[s_,f_]:= s+f; ]ListPointPlot3D[ Table[ {s, f, k[s,f]},  {s, -1, 1, 0.5}, {f, -1, 1, 0.5}]]`?

Comment: Well, It's in 3D, while I want 2D-plot. I wonder how to specify the values of k[s,f] in ListPlot for 2D ? weather a condition can be added  as: k[s,f] < 2, or to add evaluate .. I don't know. Another choice as i guss RegionPlot, but i think the function won't be plotted as points. The Graph i refered to in the paper is the perfection for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** I guess you want to color a list of 2D points using a function *like* `k[s,f]`. You can `Style` the original data and use the resulting data  with `ListPlot` to get something like Figure 2 in the linked paper.

```
dt = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2}];
```

The first 10 rows of `dt`:

```
TableForm[dt[[;; 10]], TableHeadings -> {None, {"s", "f"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
styleddt = Style[{##}, PointSize[.02],
     Piecewise[{{Orange, -1 <= k[##] <= 0}, {Green, .5 <=  k[##] <= .9}, 
      {Red, 1.2 <= k[##] <= 1.6}}, Blue]] & @@@ dt;
labels = {"-1<=k[s,f]<=0", ".5<=k[s,f]<=.9", "1.2<=k[s,f]<=1.6", "otherwise"};
colors = {Orange, Green, Red, Blue};
legend = Row[Style[##, "Panel", 18] & @@@ Transpose[{labels, colors}], Spacer[5]];

ListPlot[styleddt, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True,
 ImageSize -> 500, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabel -> legend]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the data is 3D and the third entry is obtained by applying a function like `k[s,f]` to the first two entries (like data set `dt3d` below), then the function we use to style the data is slightly different:

```
dt3d = {##, k@##} & @@@ dt;
```

The first 10 rows of `dt3d`:

```
TableForm[dt3d[[;; 10]], TableHeadings -> {None, {"s", "f", "k[s, f]"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
styleddata = Style[{#, #2}, PointSize[.02],
     Piecewise[{{Orange, -1 <= #3 <=  0}, 
      {Green, .5 <= #3 <= .9}, {Red, 1.2 <= #3 <= 1.6}},  Blue]] & @@@ dt3d;
```

We get the same picture as above using:

```
ListPlot[styleddata, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True,
         ImageSize -> 500, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabel -> legend]
```

**Original post:**

Here are few alternative ways to use 2D plots / charts to visualize your data.

**Graphics:**

```
Graphics[{PointSize[Large],
  {ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-2, 2}}][#3], Disk[{#, #2}, .1], 
     Black, Text[Style[#3, 14, Bold], {#, #2}]} & @@@ (Join @@ 
     Table[{s, f, k[s, f]}, {s, -1, 1, 0.5}, {f, -1, 1, 0.5}])}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**MatrixPlot**

```
MatrixPlot[Table[k[s, f], {s, -1, 1, 0.5}, {f, -1, 1, 0.5}], 
 DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 DataReversed -> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**BubbleChart**

```
BubbleChart[Labeled[Style[{#, #2, Abs@#3 /. 0. -> 1}, 
     ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-2, 2}}][#3]], #3] & @@@ (Join @@ 
    Table[{s, f, k[s, f]}, {s, -1, 1, 0.5}, {f, -1, 1, 0.5}]), 
 BubbleScale -> (1 &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could  in Graphics for example, to make the points of f[k,s] without being labeled by it's values. Then we can specify in condition for example to make the points for only  0< f[k,s] < 2 with a certain colour . Thanx

Comment: @S.S. please see the update.

Comment: That's great. Thanx

Comment: Please look again at my question cause it's added.

Comment: @S.S. I updated with examples of input data to clarify.

Comment: Really thanx for the explanation.