# How to 2D-plot function in three varibles with one fixed

Tags: plotting

This post is an extension of the post:

[How to 2D-plot function in two varibles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113354/how-to-2d-plot-function-in-two-varibles)

Actually I got the answer for that question from

`I guess you want to color a list of 2D points using a function like k[s,f]. You can Style the original data and use the resulting data with ListPlot.`

But I didn't understand from here:

`" If the data is 3D and the third entry is obtained by applying a
  function like k[s,f] to the first two entries (like data set dt3d
  below), then the function we use to style the data is slightly
  different:"`

I understand in the example of `td` and `styleddt` that in `Style[{##}` and `k[##]`, that `##` refers to the two variables which `k` is function of them.

But now I try to plot another function, like `Y[s,f,d]= s+f+d;`, `with -1 < s < 1`, `f= 0.5`, and `-0.5 < d < 0.5`, and I want to plot `Y[s,f,d]` only at `-2 < Y < 0`, or Piecewise can be used as in the first example to know Y values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[dt, y]
y[s_, d_, f_] := s + f + d;
dt = Transpose[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000], RandomReal[{-.5, .5}, 1000]}];
styleddt = Style[{##}, PointSize[.02], 
     Piecewise[{{Red, -2 <= y[##, .5] <= 0}},  Blue]] & @@@ dt;
labels = {"-2<=y[s,d,.5]<=0", "  otherwise"};
colors = {Red, Blue};
legend = Row[Style[##, "Panel", 18] & @@@ Transpose[{labels, colors}], Spacer[5]];

ListPlot[styleddt, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 500, PlotLabel -> legend, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["s", "Panel", 20], Style["d", "Panel", 20]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi kglr, ` dt ` answer is perfect, but can't we control RandomReal, so as to make the Y-axis scale different than X-axis scale, say on way axis (d) {-0.5,0.5} and on X-axis {0.7,1}.

Comment: @S.S., i updated with the suggested changes.

Comment: ✩  ✩  ✩ Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[y[s, 0.5, d], {s, -1, 1}, {d, -.5, .5},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{s, d, z}, -2 < y[s, 0.5, d] < 0],
 Contours -> 10, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

You can use `Plot3D` and the `RegionFunction` option.

```
Plot3D[y[s, 0.5, d], {s, -1, 1}, {d, -.5, .5},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{s, d, z}, -2 < y[s, 0.5, d] < 0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ya, but I want the plot in 2D, as the first graph in the referred post.

Comment: @S.S. It seems like overkill.  Why not `ContourPlot`?