# ListPlot function in 2D- plan in two varibles

Tags: plotting, conditional

Suppose a function `f[s,k]`. How to Listplot this function in `2D` plot in (s,k) plan, such that  `1 < f[s,k] < 6` ?

This post is similar for : [How to 2D-plot function in two varibles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113354/how-to-2d-plot-function-in-two-varibles)

However I have no here several regions for `f[s,k]`, so I don't want to use  `Piecewise` any more .. I think we may use `If` here, any help ?

Comment: Do you mean like this: `RegionPlot[1 < f[s, k] < 6, {s, -2, 2}, {k, -2, 2}]`?

Comment: No, I want to make `Listplot` .. because you know the function will become as in the figures in the referred post , separate points ..

Comment: Answer 1 in this post is fine , but only now there is no need for `Piecewise` .. it's only conditional function being plotted in its 2 variables plan ..

Answer (score 2):

If the data is in `{x,y,z}` form you can use `ListDensityPlot`.

```
f[s_, k_] = Sin[s 2 Pi] Sin[k 2 Pi];
data = Flatten[Table[{s, k, f[s, k]}, {s, 0, 1, 0.05}, {k, 0, 1, 0.05}], 1];
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]

If it is just a 2D array of data you can use `MatrixPlot`

```
f[s_, k_] = Sin[s 2 Pi] Sin[k 2 Pi];
data = Table[f[s, k], {s, 0, 1, 0.05}, {k, 0, 1, 0.05}];
MatrixPlot[data, PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]

Or with discrete points

```
f[s_, k_] = Sin[s 2 Pi] Sin[k 2 Pi];
data = Flatten[Table[{s, k, f[s, k]}, {s, 0, 1, 0.1}, {k, 0, 1, 0.1}],    1];

min = Min@data[[All, 3]]; max = Max@data[[All, 3]];

Grid[{{Graphics[{ColorData["Rainbow"][(#[[3]] - min)/(max - min)], 
   PointSize[Large], Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]]} & /@ data, 
   ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True],  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}]}}]
```

[image]

You can choose any colorscheme you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to plot List of points instead

Comment: Your data is `{x,y,z}` format?

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have one criterion, this will do if I understand correctly:

```
ListPlot[Table[{s, If[1 < f[s,k] < 6, k, Null]}, {s, smin, smax, ds}, {k, kmin, kmax, dk}]]
```

Comment: Can't we  just use the code in the referred post (Answer 1), but avoid `Piecewise` ?

Comment: My understanding of that referred code was that you color the points `{s, k}` and the color is chosen based on what criterion is satisfied. Here there is only one criterion, so why bother with custom styles if all points will have the same color? Or do you want one color for `1 < f[s,k] < 6` and another for `Not[1 < f[s,k] < 6]`?